# Xamarin: Run-time and build time errors using iOS universal static library

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin

I'm using the cocoapod [SWRevealViewController](http://cocoapods.org/pods/SWRevealViewController) with [Xamarin .net binding](https://github.com/Vandborg/SWRevealViewController-XamarinBinding) in my current Xamarin project. I made a new static library locally using XCode and added the SWRevealViewController pod to also build for arm64 architecture. I build the new library both for simulator (i386 and x86_64) and device (armv7 and arm64), and used lipo to combine the two initial libraries into one universal library. Using: "file lib.a", I can see that the new universal library contains all four architectures.

When I replace the original library SWRevealViewControllerSDK.a with the new static library in the Xamarin-project, I get two issues:

o For simulator I get a run-time error:

```
Unknown class SWRevealViewController in Interface Builder file.
```

o For device I get a build time error:

```
MTOUCHTASK: error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: _OBJC_CLASS_$_SWRevealViewController. If '_OBJC_CLASS_$_SWRevealViewController' is a protocol from a third-party binding, please check that it has the [Protocol] attribute in its api definition file, otherwise verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
MTOUCHTASK: error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: _OBJC_CLASS_$_SWRevealViewControllerSegue. If '_OBJC_CLASS_$_SWRevealViewControllerSegue' is a protocol from a third-party binding, please check that it has the [Protocol] attribute in its api definition file, otherwise verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
MTOUCHTASK: error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log.
```

If I instead of using lipo to make universal library, just add the two initial static libraries for simulator and device, everything works fine, just getting linker warnings for the library not used for the target architecture.

Anyone got a clue why I got the issues with the universal library while it works fine using the two initial libraries?

Comment: I tried to redo adding of the device and simulator libraries, but then I got the same run-time error as with universal library running on the simulator. Hence, not so clear when the problem occurs.

Comment: Can you add `-v -v -v -v` to the additional mtouch arguments and then pastebin the full build log (after a rebuild)? You can also try using `nm -arch all SWRevealViewControllerSDK.a | grep SWRevealViewController` to see if the class is actually there.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue adding the universal library only, but now it suddenly worked for all architectures - no build-time or run-time errors - strange! Anyway, thanks for your attention, @RolfBjarneKvinge!